# HTTP POST in .NET Micro Framework - Exception on GetRequestStream()

Tags: c#, .net, http, post, .net-micro-framework

I am attempting to make an HTTP POST from a Fez Panda II microcontroller board using the .NET Micro Framework (C#), but the following code throws an exception you can see after the code snippet while I attempt to get the request stream. I can't seem to find anything about this particular error anywhere on the internet.

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.urlofthewebsite.com/Word/");

    string name = "00ABCDEFDEADBEEF";
    string rawData = "2012-02-08\t14:53:08\t755F66";

    try
    {
            string postData = "deviceID=" + name + "&rawData=" + rawData;

            Debug.Print(postData);

            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            //request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            //request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            //Set parameters of web request for HTTP POST
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            request.KeepAlive = false;

            //Create a stream to send the post data to
            //ERROR OCCURS HERE
            Stream postDataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

            etc.
```

Debug output:

```
    #### Exception System.Exception - 0x00000000 (1) ####
    #### Message: DNS server IP address was not found.
    #### GHIElectronics.NETMF.Net.Dns::GetHostEntry [IP: 0038] ####
    #### GHIElectronics.NETMF.Net.HttpWebRequest::EstablishConnection [IP: 00e1] ####
    #### GHIElectronics.NETMF.Net.HttpWebRequest::SubmitRequest [IP: 0013] ####
    #### GHIElectronics.NETMF.Net.HttpWebRequest::GetRequestStream [IP: 0008] ####
    #### Fresh_Step.Program::httpPostRawData [IP: 0052] ####
    #### Fresh_Step.Program::Main [IP: 0004] ####
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in GHIElectronics.NETMF.W5100.Http.dll
```

What could the problem be? Any help is very much appreciated. If additional information is required, I'll be glad to provide it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give us a link to the page you're submitting to?

Answer (score 0):

The Panda can't determine where www.urlofthewebsite.com is. This is probably because you haven't configured the DNS servers in the network configuration of the Panda.

Use the MFDeploy tool (part of the .Net Micro Framework) to configure the network settings for the device. Run the tool, ensure that it is connected to the right device by using the dropdowns at the top of the window, then choose Target -> Configuration -> Network to open the network configuration screen. Make sure that DNS Primary Address contains the IP address of your local DNS server.

See this MSDN article for more information on the MFDeploy tool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc544584.aspx

If you have your device configured to use DHCP, make sure that it's getting an IP address and getting a DNS server that knows where www.urlofthewebsite.com is.

Comment: Through the MFDeploy tool the device pings just fine but when I go through you steps listed above: Target -> Configuration -> Network an error window pops up displaying the message:  

**'Error: Invalid configuration sector'**  

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Haven't seen that before. The easiest way to resolve it would probably be to reflash the device with the latest firmware.